# Adding/Removing CSS on page load

Tags: jquery, hash

So, my trouble is that I have "selectors" that show you what menu you're on. I use two classes, the `selected` and `unselected` classes.

When the page loads, I load based on the hash in the URL, and that loads fine (implying that my function for when the page load, works!)

Now, I have a separate method, called `setSelect()` which basically removes/adds the CSS to the menu items based on a variable that is declared at the beginning of my JS document.

So here's the code (I cut a lot out and only kept relevant parts)

```
var jlLocation = 1;

function setSelect() {
        if(jlLocation==1) {
            $('#location1').removeClass('unselected');  
            $('#location1').addClass('selected');
            $('#location2').removeClass('selected');    
            $('#location2').addClass('unselected');
        }
        else if(jlLocation==2) {
            $('#location1').removeClass('selected');    
            $('#location1').addClass('unselected');
            $('#location2').removeClass('unselected');  
            $('#location2').addClass('selected');
        }
 }

$(function(){
                // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
                // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
                $(window).hashchange( function(){
                    hash = location.hash;
                    document.title = 'Joy Luck ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '- ' ) || '' ) + ''; // Set the page title based on the hash.
                    setSelect();
                    if (hash == "#Home") {
                        showHome();
                    }
                    else if (hash == "#Accommodations") {
                        showAccommodations();   
                    }       

                    $('#menu a').each(function(){
                        var that = $(this);
                        that[ that.attr( 'href' ) == hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
                    });
                  })
                  $(window).hashchange();  
                });
```

Again, if I load on the `#home` hash or `#accommodations` those methods run, but the `setSelect();` method does not work. All methods are placed before the method that loads the hashes, so that shouldn't be an issue.

**EDIT**

I'm aware `setSelect()` wasn't being called. That's because no matter where I call it in that method, it just didn't work. But, to help out, I put it in.

Comment: Is it a typo your code is missing a } on the first function to close it? Also you really need to reuse selectors. Do not do $('#location1') multiple times. Chain them! $("xxx").addClass("x").removeClass("y");

Comment: Sorry, it didn't survive my viscous methods of copy and paste. It exists in my original code.

Comment: The variable `jlLocation` never changes.

Comment: That is correct, it does not change in this example. However that's not an issue, as even if it's 1, the conditional will fire. But the problem is that the method does not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're never calling the `setSelect()` function (Or at least your code shows that)

Comment: That's my mistake. I had removed it after it effectively did nothing.